# RESTful API write security

Tags: javascript, rest, reactjs, restful-authentication

I've recently started using modern front end technologies like React/Angular and as a result have started using tools like [JSON Server](https://scotch.io/tutorials/json-server-as-a-fake-rest-api-in-frontend-development) to recreate dummy restful db interactions.

My understanding is that most rest api's authenticate via some kind of token and secret that is either passed as part of the url or as a header. This seems fine for retrieving data, but is it not risky exposing these login credentials in a front end language like JS when writing is possible?

My thinking is that all it would take is a simple view source for somebody to steal my token/secret and potentially start populating my db with data.

Comment: Neither login credentials nor tokens are hardcoded in JS/HTML, they are generated once user is authenticated and authorized to access particular resource on server with some kind of token, all the subsequent requests to server is passed with such tokens

Answer (score 0):

In the problem that you describe the client (browser) has the login credentials because the server provide them. There is no "exposing" as the credentials are already exposed. Exposing your credentials to every client means that there is no security.

When we talk about security we consider as a client the browser not the real person that operates the browser. As you said, the real person can access all the browser's data.

To secure your API the secret key must be kept secret. This means that each client has a different key and uses it to get their data/services from your RESTfull server.

In a simple senario this key can be used/managed like the session id.
The client should first pass through an authorization process (login maybe) and then a temporary key can be generated for the client's session.

Generally, a key is converted to rights. If every client by default has the key, everyone has the default rights, so you may also remove the key and set the default rights to every request.

A client that you don't want to have full access to your db should have a key that gives him limited access to your db.

On the other hand, if the client provides the key, this is secure. For example a php code on a server that uses the secret key for accessing your API.